# Copying the parents nodes upto the root to create multiple items

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and I am working on a tricky xml transformation requirement.
My source xml is as mentioned below.

```
<Level_0>
    <Level_1>
        <Level_2>
            <Level_3>hello</Level_3>
            <Level_4>
                <Header>
                    <Value>SomeValue</Value>
                </Header>
                <SalesInvoice>
                    <Item>
                        <Detail>
                            <Position>1</Position>
                        </Detail>
                    </Item>
                </SalesInvoice>
                <SalesInvoice>
                    <Item>
                        <Detail>
                            <Position>2</Position>
                        </Detail>
                    </Item>
                </SalesInvoice>
                <SalesInvoice>
                    <Item>
                        <Detail>
                            <Position>3</Position>
                        </Detail>
                    </Item>
                </SalesInvoice>
            </Level_4>
        </Level_2>
    </Level_1>
</Level_0>
```

Requirement - I need to have each item having its parents up to the level_1, means output should be as mentioned below. Basically, everything should be repeated for each Item from level_1.

```
<Level_0>
    <Level_1>
        <Level_2>
            <Level_3>hello</Level_3>
            <Level_4>
                <Header>
                    <Value>SomeValue</Value>
                </Header>
                <SalesInvoice>
                    <Item>
                        <Detail>
                            <Position>1</Position>
                        </Detail>
                    </Item>
                </SalesInvoice>
            </Level_4>
        </Level_2>
    </Level_1>
    <Level_1>
        <Level_2>
            <Level_3>hello</Level_3>
            <Level_4>
                <Header>
                    <Value>SomeValue</Value>
                </Header>
                <SalesInvoice>
                    <Item>
                        <Detail>
                            <Position>2</Position>
                        </Detail>
                    </Item>
                </SalesInvoice>
            </Level_4>
        </Level_2>
    </Level_1>
    <Level_1>
        <Level_2>
            <Level_3>hello</Level_3>
            <Level_4>
                <Header>
                    <Value>SomeValue</Value>
                </Header>
                <SalesInvoice>
                    <Item>
                        <Detail>
                            <Position>3</Position>
                        </Detail>
                    </Item>
                </SalesInvoice>
            </Level_4>
        </Level_2>
    </Level_1>
</Level_0>
```

XSLT I tried. But I am getting weird output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:template match="SalesInvoice">
        <NewInvoice>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../../../../Level_1/descendant::*[not(name()='SalesInvoice' or ancestor::SalesInvoice)]"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </NewInvoice>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to approach it. For each of the `SalesInvoice` process, apply-templates starting from it's `Level_1`, but pass through the `SalesInvoice` as a param (I used [@tunnel](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#tunnel-params), but you could explicitly define the param and pass it through at each level in each template). In the template matching `SalesInvoice` only copy the content if it's the `$invoice-context`, otherwise it gets dropped.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Level_0">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="//SalesInvoice">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::Level_1" mode="repeat">
                    <xsl:with-param name="invoice-context" select="." tunnel="yes"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="repeat">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="repeat"/>    
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="SalesInvoice" mode="repeat">
        <xsl:param name="invoice-context" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:if test="generate-id(.) eq generate-id($invoice-context)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I must say, this is magic Mads :) . You made my day, I have had a quick execution and I see it is the perfect output I wanted.  I will take some time to decode your solution. Many thanks for your help, I wish, I could award you a million points for this solution. Great work indeed, Stack overflow is the best website where genius people like you are helping others :)